# Background image is repeating in cshtml file

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am creating mvc4 application. I want to set background in layout.cshtml. Issue is that my background image is repeating even after setting a tag of background-repeat:no-repeat. I Google it a lot and tried different approaches told there. But none of them helped me out. Any help in this regard? My background image is paced in the Images folder created in my app. Here is the simple code of my layout.cshtml file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body style="background-image:url(Images/blue.jpg)" "background-repeat:no-repeat">


@RenderBody()
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: it genuinely css question not asp.net

Comment: @Rabia Mehmood can u send your problem in screen shot

Comment: @Rabia Mehmood set margin:0px and padding:0px;

Comment: @rJ7 the issue is still there. I cant post screen shot as i dont have enough reputations here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You error is in the line:

```
<body style="background-image:url(Images/blue.jpg)" "background-repeat:no-repeat">
```

in which you're using too many `"`.

You need to use semi-colons instead to differentiate between one style and the next. So instead, make it:

```
<body style="background-image:url(Images/blue.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat">
```

for it to work.

---

**Side Note**

Styling inline is generally avoided, as it leads to multiple problems from a css point of view. Try setting this inside your **css file instead**.

Your css would then include:

```
body{
    background:url(Images/blue.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100%; /*if you wanted to 'fill' the page to max size without cropping*/
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/hnvpdkgn/)

To completely 'fill' the page, you need to add a size to your html as well,

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/hnvpdkgn/1/)

Comment: yes i put the semicolons but still not getting the desired output.

Comment: what is your 'desired' output? Do you want to stretch this image to fill the page? Or what exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Give inline style as follows:

```
<body style="background-image:url(Images/blue.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;">
```

Comment: @Rabia Mehmood if you think this is the answer then tick my answer

Comment: @rJ7i want it to be on my whole page. In this way some of my page lefts empty.

Comment: @Rabia Mehmood add background:cover style

Comment: it is giving me an error on cover style. <body style="background-image:url(Images/blue.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;background:coverstyle">

Comment: @Rabia Mehmood <body style="background-image:url(Images/blue.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;backgro‌​und:cover;">

Comment: i tried this way too. But still it is giving an error on background that "background is not a known CSS property name".

Comment: @Rabia Mehmood add height: 667px;

Comment: i m still getting the withe space. I had already tried it with height and width attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to, you need to put the single quotations between inside the url also you missed one forward slash as well.
    `<body style="background-image:url('/Images/blue.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat;">`